# set different colors for each column in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to set different colors for each column in Highcharts graph dynamically. My Highcharts graph is:

```js
options = {
         chart: {
             renderTo: 'chart',
             type: 'column',
             width: 450
         },
         title: {
             text: 'A glance overview at your contest’s status'
         },
         xAxis: {
             categories: ['Approved Photos', 'Pending Approval Photos', 
                          'Votes', 'Entrants'],
             labels: {
                 //rotation: -45,
                 style: {
                     font: 'normal 9px Verdana, sans-serif, arial'
                 }
             }
         },
         yAxis: {
             allowDecimals: false,
             min: 0,
             title: {
                 text: 'Amount'
             }
         },
         legend: {
             enabled: false
         },
         series: []
     };
     series = {
         name: "Amount",
         data: [],
         dataLabels: {
             enabled: true,
             color: '#000000',
             align: 'right',
             x: -10,
             y: 20,
             formatter: function () {
                 return this.y;
             },
             style: {
                 font: 'normal 13px Verdana, sans-serif'
             }
     }
 };
```

The data is set this way:

```
for (var i in Data) {
  if (parseInt(Data[i]) != 0) {
    series.data.push(parseInt(Data[i]));
  } else {
    series.data.push(null);
  }
}
options.series.push(series);
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

How can I dynamically set different colors for each data point in this loop?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

When you add the value to the series.data you can also set the color using the point options e.g

```
series.data.push({ y: parseInt(Data[i]), color: '#FF0000' });
```

For more details about the point options see https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#color

Comment: Hi! It's me again... How i can set column width by data. For example: if data is 23 i want to set column width 100px, and if data is 123 it will be 110px. I need this option for putt data in the middle of column.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how you'd do this in highcharts.

Comment: you can plotOptions->series->linewidth to set the width. But, that would fixed width for all the bars in the chart. May be you can set it using the max value. http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series--lineWidth

Comment: That documentation link is broken

Comment: Thank you for this answer !

Comment: @shanabus I updated the link, works now! wow three years later haha.

Comment: Any solution like this for HighStock charts?

Answer (score 85):

Here is another solution with the latest version of Highcharts (currently 3.0).

Set the [colorByPoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.colorByPoint) option to true and define the [color sequence](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors) that you want.

```
options = {
    chart: {...},
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            colorByPoint: true
        }
    },
    colors: [
        '#ff0000',
        '#00ff00',
        '#0000ff'
    ]
}
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/DwW3m/) based upon Highcharts [Column with rotated labels demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels)

Comment: note that this solution works on bar charts as well as column.  Just change 'column' to 'bar' in the plotOptions array

Comment: Precisely what I needed and much easier to implement than the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Any way to do something like this for multiple series? Not globally? I have a line chart and column, but I want my line color to be different than what I set for the column series. In the column chart, certain columns need to be different colors as well.

Answer (score 9):

Try either of these approaches:

Approach 1:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({ colors: ['#3B97B2', '#67BC42', '#FF56DE', '#E6D605', '#BC36FE'] });
```

Approach 2:

```
var colors = ['#3B97B2', '#67BC42', '#FF56DE', '#E6D605', '#BC36FE', '#000'];

 $('#bar_chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'              
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false                       
                }
            }
        },         

        series: [{
            name: '',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Blue',
                y: 5.78,
                color: colors[0]

            }, {
                name: 'Green',
                y: 5.19,
                color: colors[1]

            }, {
                name: 'Pink',
                y: 32.11,
                color: colors[2]

            }, {
                name: 'Yellow',
                y: 10.04,
                color: colors[3]

            }, {
                name: 'Purple',
                y: 19.33,
                color: colors[4]

            }]
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the color to an array of different colors? For example, I am returning what colors I want from my data, so I want to use that instead of manually setting it, and certain columns have certain colors.

Answer (score 0):

i had colors from API response and 2 series. second series with dynamic colors.

following is sample to set dynamic colors while series mapping.

```js
const response = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Mango',
    'color': '#83d8b6',
    'stock': 12.0,
    'demand': 28,
  },
  {
    id ': 2,
    'name': 'Banana',
    'color': '#d7e900',
    'stock': 12.0,
    'demand': 28,
  }
];
let chartData: {
  categories: [],
  series: []
};
chartData.categories = response.map(x => x.name);
chartData.series.push({
  name: 'Series 1',
  type: 'column',
  data: response.map(x => x.demand)
});
chartData.series.push({
  name: 'Series 2',
  type: 'column',
  data: response.map(x => ({
    y: x.stock,
    color: x.color // set color here dynamically
  }))
});
console.log('chartData: ', chartData);
```

you could also read more about [Highcharts series Point and Marker](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#point)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ArrayColor = new Array();
var sColor = (nCheckValue == 0) ? 'Green' : 'Red';
ArrayColor.push(sColor);

options = {
    chart: {...},
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            colorByPoint: true
        }
    },
    colors: ArrayColor
}
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.