# High charts: Set Each Bar In a Multi-Series Bar Graphs To a Different Color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to set the color of each individual bar to a different color in a multi series highCharts graphs.

here is the data as it comes in:

```
{
    "yAxisText": "",
    "yAxisUnit": "%",
    "statusCode": "OK",
    "chartType": "column",
    "categories": [
        "Basic",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3+",
        "4+"
    ],
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "test1",
            "data": [
                56.6,
                17.3,
                8.6,
                17.5,
                12
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "test2",
            "data": [
                46.5,
                16,
                15.4,
                22.1,
                33
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm able to make each data set a different color or each category a different color, but I can't figure out how to make each individual bar a different color.
So essentially for this data there would be 8 bars with 8 different colors.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set different colors for each column in highcharts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737409/set-different-colors-for-each-column-in-highcharts)

Comment: Here you go, it's a mix of few options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16169440/5388620

Comment: thanks, I don't think it was a duplicate of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set array of colors and then apply each color per poiny by colorByPoint option.

```
{
   colors:['blue','red','green']
},
series:[{
   colorByPoint: true,
   data:[1,2,3]
}]
```

Comment: That's not quite what I am looking for.  I made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yoleg24/yb5f6rsL/) to demonstrate what I am currently getting.  What I would like is for each individual bar to be a different color.  So in this fiddle there would be 10 different colored bars.  Thanks!

Comment: You can prepare an array of points and then in the load event, call update action on each column. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yb5f6rsL/2/

Comment: Great.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!