# Gradient in column highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am plotting a column chart using highcharts but what I want is the color to be gradient across all the columns, i.e. each column should have a different color.

I am able to put n-gradient in n-column but not a single across gradient across the complete graph.

Attaching the brief idea:
[image]

Comment: I think the answer is already there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737409/set-different-colors-for-each-column-in-highcharts?rq=1

Comment: @PaulLemarchand it is color by point for which I need to have numerous colors which I know, but what I want is that i specify start and end color and it generates a gradient for the chart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was an interesting idea so I took a stab at it. I was able to get it something approaching what you want using a variant of the Highcharts monochrome fill PIE [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-monochrome). The tricky part is knowing how many data you have so that the brightness calculation doesn't get maxed out before end of series. If you know how many data points you are going to have you can pre-fill the prototype or you can make it a function that takes number of points as a param. Anyway, here is my attempt:

```
$(function() {
  // Make monochrome colors and set them as default for all pies
  Highcharts.getOptions().plotOptions.column.colors = (function() {
    var colors = [],
      base = '#e2535c', //Set to the starting color you want.
      i;
    // This is the part you need to setup. 
    //The "50" is just some arbitrarily large value for this demo.
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
      // Start out with a darkened base color (negative brighten), and end
      // up with a much brighter color
      // I modified the math here to use 25 as the increment.
      // Your needs may vary.
      colors.push(Highcharts.Color(base).brighten((i - 3) / 25).get());
    }
    return colors;
  }());

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        colorByPoint: true // This needs to be true.
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
  });
});
```

Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/xq44wwsc/). I am pretty sure this can be done in another way but this got me 90% of the way there.

After some more searching of methods that can generate color gradients in javascript I came across [RainbowVis-JS](https://github.com/anomal/RainbowVis-JS). This lets you set the start and end color (along with any itermediate colors) as well as how many stops you need. I Set up a way to do this with the `chart.events.load` method. What I am doing is getting how many points are in my `series.data` and setting it as the range. Then I loop over the data points in the data and using the index value I return the color and update the point with [`Point.update`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update):

```
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  type: 'column',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var rainbow = new Rainbow();
      // Set start and end colors
      rainbow.setSpectrum('#e2535c', '#ea9056');

      // Set the min/max range
      var theData = this.series[0].data;
      var rangeLow = 0;
      var rangeHigh = theData.length
      rainbow.setNumberRange(rangeLow, rangeHigh);

      // Loop over data points and update the point.color value
      for (index = 0; index < theData.length; ++index) {

        this.series[0].data[index].update({
          color: '#' + rainbow.colourAt(index)
        });
      }
    }
  }
},
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/q360qjyn/).

Comment: Pretty close, but here you are specifying a single color. Can you by any chance specify two colors and able to get colors between them?

Comment: @void, I believe you could. Would need to setup stops based upon how many points you have.

Comment: Can you give me a brief idea of how to achieve this using stops?

Comment: @void, New approach incoming.

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could guide me a little.

Comment: Thats perfect! Thank you so much.