# Change HighCharts of type Column Bar Graph Color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to change the Color of Two categories in high charts? Below is my code:

```
exec_dashboard_load_graph(
    'exec_dashboard_collection_disbursement_graph',
    response,
    ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']                    
);  

function exec_dashboard_load_graph(id,data, x){
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart(id, {
        chart: {type: 'column'},
        title: {text: 'Annual Collection and Disbursement Summary'},
        subtitle:{text: 'City Goverment of Butuan'},
        xAxis: {categories: x,crosshair: true},
        yAxis: {min: 0,title: {text: 'Amount (Peso Value)'}},
        tooltip:{
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b> {point.y:.1f} Php </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {column: {pointPadding: 0.2,borderWidth: 0}},
        series: data    
    });
}
```

The data variable contains the value below:

[image]

Comment: You can add your color inside your specific dataPoint, here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/bygzgc9h/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the color option with the series.
Let's say you are specifying your series as :

```
data=[{x:10,y:12}]
```

Transform it to the following :

```
data=[{x:10,y:12,color:'#FFFFFF'}]
```

The color must be added where you are populating the series , i.e , where you specify the x/y values for your columns.

Also I found this answer which could be duplicate to your issue , check it out :
[set-different-colors-for-each-column-in-highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737409/set-different-colors-for-each-column-in-highcharts)